# Button that goes to another activity on android keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am trying to make a `gridview` gallery.When you click a photo from the gallery it opens in a different **activity**.
The problem is that if the user doesnt have a button to go back on his phone he cant go back to the gridview.
So i made a button to go back. The code for the button:

```
public class Fullscreen extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView imageView;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);


        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GoToGallery();
            }


        });






        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);




        Intent i = getIntent();

        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");


        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.imageArray[position]);
    }


    public void GoToGallery(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Fullscreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

this is located to the new fullscreen activity and the first time you load the app it works..but just once if you open a second image and push the button it crashes.
the only warning I get is: `Method invocation 'getInt' may produce 'NullPointerException'`
but I dont know how to deal with it and I read that it doesnt matter most of the times.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are not going to the different activity you are starting the same activity again look at your code :

```
public void GoToGallery(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Fullscreen.class); //Fullscreen.class is same activity from where you are starting
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And the other thing is that when you started the same activity it should be started without any excuse to you like exception that you found that was `because you are not putting any extras` when you started the same activity but you are trying to `getInt` so in my opinion try this code it may help you :

```
public void GoToGallery(){
    onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your GoToGallery function open the same activity Fullscreen again and without passing id due to which the line `imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.imageArray[position]);` causes NullPointerException

Update the button OnClickListener to fix the issue. Call finish() method to close current activity and move back to the previous one.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               finish();
            }
        });
```